# ImportError: cannot import name 'myClass' from 'myModule': where did I mess up?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get into unit testing with Python, of which I'm severely out of practice, and I'm running into issues with importing.

It's been a long, long time since I did Python and I'm trying to get into unit testing too. I've mostly been working with bash until recently so I may have overlooked something. It's on Python 3 but I think the version ultimately doesn't matter. Only going to show relevant code.

```
Directory structure:
myProject/
|
\keter/
|    |-keter.py
|    |-__init__.py
|
\tests/
|    |- test_first.py
```

in keter.py

```
import os
import zipfile
import re
import xml.dom.minidom
class Converter:
    def my_function(params):
        #do stuff
```

in test_first.py

```
import unittest
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
from keter import Converter

class TestConverter(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_instantiate(self):
        my_converter = Converter()
        self.assertIsInstance(my_converter,Converter)
```

On attempting to run the test...

```
$ python -m unittest discover
E
======================================================================
ERROR: test_first (unittest.loader._FailedTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_first
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path_to_python\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 436, in _find_test_path
    module = self._get_module_from_name(name)
  File "path_to_python\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 377, in _get_module_from_name
    __import__(name)
  File "path_to_project\tests\test_first.py", line 5, in <module>
    from keter import Converter
ImportError: cannot import name 'Converter' from 'keter' (..\keter\__init__.py)


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Comment: `Converter` is in `keter/keter.py`, not in `keter/__init__.py` so you need `from keter.keter import Converter` OR move `Converter` to `keter/__init__.py`

Comment: Could you post that as an answer?

Comment: furas, that one worked. Could you post it as an answer so I can accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

try to change your test_first.py like this.

```
import unittest
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
import keter

class TestConverter(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_instantiate(self):
        my_converter = keter.Converter()
        self.assertIsInstance(my_converter,Converter)
```

Comment: ``` AttributeError: module 'keter' has no attribute 'Converter' ```